# Yarn is failing to install packages for my angular(9.1.1) app

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg

I was using npm as package manager,suddenly it failed to install packages saying "unknown error while decoding JSON..".Then I fall back to yarn and set it as my package manager(global).The error is resolved but I am getting following errors:

```
/ Installing packages...warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > less > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > stylus > css-parse > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
error Couldn't find package "@babel/core@7.9.0" required by "@angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.901.1" on the "npm" registry.
Error: Couldn't find package "@babel/generator@7.9.3" required by "@angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.901.1" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:323:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "@babel/generator@^7.9.5" required by "@babel/traverse@^7.7.4" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:323:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "@babel/core@^7.7.5" required by "istanbul-lib-instrument@^4.0.1" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:323:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: `rm pakage-lock.json` and `rm -rf node_modules` then try

Comment: try to ad `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular` i hope it working.